# A HTTP request and a single WebSocket message followed by disconnect-- What is more expensive over the network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http, websocket

Hypothetically, we cannot utilise an open, two-way connection with a WebSocket client due to a server limitation. We can, however, open a WebSocket connection receive a message and then instantly disconnect. Alternatively, you can make a a GET request for the same information.

WebSockets originate with a HTTP request upgrade then the socket begins. If you can make one message delivery with Websockets the header is reduced. Then HTTP to a RESTful endpoint takes one single request.

Considering the network traffic which method requires less to retrieve the same information?

Answer (score 1):

Purely from a network perspective a single HTTP GET request will be a more efficient as it is just a single request/response.  The webSocket becomes potentially lots more efficient if you are going to keep the webSocket open and send lots of traffic over it, particularly if you're sending lots of small messages. But, for a temporal webSocket, the extra overhead in establishing the webSocket connection makes it less efficient for one request/response.

Here's an illustration of what happens in each:

**HTTP GET request:**

```
Establish TCP socket (back and forths to establish the socket, more if TLS)

// http request
GET /someURL HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8000
OtherHeaders: otherValues
```

And, an http response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
OtherHeaders: otherValues

data...

Close socket
```

**For a webSocket:**

```
Establish TCP Socket  (back and forths to establish the socket, more if TLS)

// webSocket connection request
GET /someURL HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8000
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

// webSocket connection response
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=

// Then send actual webSocket message request in webSocket data frame format

// Then receive webSocket message response in webSocket data frame format (if response required)

Close socket
```

So, because of some additional overhead establishing the webSocket connection, there are more roundtrips between client and server for the temporal webSocket connection.  This is even easier to understand when you see that establishing a webSocket connection all starts with an http request/response and THEN and only then do you send the actual data over the established webSocket connection.

Whereas with an http connection, you send the actual request immediately.

> Considering the network traffic which method requires less to retrieve the same information?

For one single request/response, the plain HTTP request/response would use less network traffic because it avoids the extra overhead of setting up the webSocket connection.

> WebSockets originate with a HTTP request upgrade then the socket begins. If you can make one message delivery with Websockets the header is reduced.

Yes, webSockets let you send some types of data more efficiently as they let you send only the payload you want to send without lots of extra headers, but for only one request, you have a full-on http request/response just to set up the webSocket connection so you don't get to realize that net savings when only using the webSocket connection for one message.  If (as I presume you already realize), if you get to keep the webSocket connection open for awhile and send many small messages over it, then it can be a lot more efficient than plain HTTP.  But, that isn't the case you apparently have.